# How to set the height of an iframe such that all of its content is set to 100% to a div of height 40%

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to set height of an iframe that renders powerbi dashboard.

My requirements are as follows:

1. All the content from the iframe should be set to a height of 100% and should be rendered inside a div of height 40%

Here is a screen shot of what I am trying to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8vRQ.png)

I have tried setting height to all the parent tag but it just isn't working.

Please help.

```js
async showDashboard(rpConfig: IDashboardEmbedConfiguration) {
    let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory); 
    let dashboardContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('dashboardContainer');

      powerbi.reset(dashboardContainer)
    
    console.log(rpConfig)
      let dashboard = powerbi.embed(dashboardContainer, rpConfig)
      console.log(dashboard)
      // this.dashboardConfig = {}

      this.loadedDashboard = true;
    }
  }
```

```css
.row2{
    height: 40%;
    .tabContainer{
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      .powerBiBlock{
        height: 100%;
        .dashboardContainer{
          height: 100%;
          .iframe{
            height: 50%;
            //overflow-y: hidden;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row2" id="ButtonEl">
    <div class="tabContainer">
      <div class="margin50">
        <div class="top-tab btn btn-primary" (click)="toggle()">
          <p><i class="arrow down"></i></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="powerBiBlock">
        <div id="dashboardContainer" class="dashboardContainer">
          <div id="dashboardContainer" class="dashboardContainer"></div>
        </div>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't think your css is valid; are you using something special for your CSS?

Comment: Where is the `iframe` in your HTML?

Comment: My iframe is inside dashboardContainer which I am creating using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    
.dashboardContainer > iframe{
    height: 40% !important;
          }
```

Comment: I've removed . from the iframe, but this still isn't working.

Comment: you can put height="40%" inside the iframe. or put height:40% !important; then let me know if it works

Comment: @AhmedataulKareem put the above css on your css.

Comment: Tried this out. Unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: @AhmedataulKareem if the iframe is inside the dashboardcontainer try the above code. then let me know

Comment: Don't know if it's gonna work for your implementation but you could also try `vh` instead of `%` ?

Comment: @Crystal the iframe is loaded dynamically by the power bi dashboard tag. I am adding the DOM code that I am using to generate a dashboard from token.

Comment: @DennizVDraanen Tried that but it didn't worked out.

Comment: I probably need to see more of your code atleast because something is probably wrong around it or something is preventing it. try to add a dispaly property on it like display:block or display:contents see if thats gonna affect to push it up on your DOM

Comment: Sure @Crystal let me try that.